# Problems with parsing XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I'm building a Windows Phone 8 App using a recipe API, the API returns data in XML and up to this point I've not had many problems with parsing API responses, however, after making a search for a recipe, a user should then be able to tap on a particular search result and see more information on that recipe, this is a Pivot page with three headers:

- Details (Which contains the recipe name, image and description)
- Ingredients (Obviously listing the ingredients and quantities)
- Instructions (Contains the prep and cooking instructions)

I have no problem getting the elements for the Details and Instructions pages as there is only one of each of these elements in the xml returned by the API, however with Ingredients, each ingredient has its own section in the xml, so I thought a foreach loop in the code would be able to get all the details into a list, however, when running the app and navigating to this page, the app seems to load multiples of ALL the information, including items on the Details and Instructions pages.

So, there are now lots of the same image, title and decryption displayed on the details page, lots of the same instructions on the instructions page and lots of the same ingredient on the ingredients page. I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this as everything I try doesn't work.

Removing the foreach loop from the code below stops the app loading loads of the same information, but obviously without any ingredients, please see the code below, I'm unable to post an API link because there is a limit to how many requests I can make per hour, and inserting it here formats it in an unclear way, does anyone know any steps to try and fix this issue?

The code:

```
void bigOvenRecipe_RecipeDetailsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
    Details content = new Details();
    List<Details> contentList = new List<Details>();

    try
    {
        content.RecipeImage = xdoc.Root.Element("ImageURL").Value;
        content.Title = xdoc.Root.Element("Title").Value;
        content.Description = xdoc.Root.Element("Description").Value;
        content.Instructions = xdoc.Root.Element("Instructions").Value;
        contentList.Add(content);

        foreach (XElement item in xdoc.Elements("Recipe").Elements("Ingredients").Elements("Ingredient"))
        {
            content.IngredientName = item.Element("Name").Value;
            content.IngredientQuantity = item.Element("Quantity").Value;
            content.IngredientUnit = item.Element("Unit").Value;
            contentList.Add(content);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error was encountered while performing this request: " + error.Message);
    }

    detailsList.ItemsSource = contentList.ToList();
    ingredientsList.ItemsSource = contentList.ToList();
    instructionsList.ItemsSource = contentList.ToList();
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the input XML so that we have a SSCCCE? http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One glaring issue that I see is that you keep adding the same `content` object to `contentList`.

I'm guessing that `Details` is a reference type, and `content` is only a reference to that one `Details` object.

your entire contentList is just a bunch of references to the same object.

Try instantiating a new object for each ingredient.

```
foreach (XElement item in xdoc.Elements("Recipe").Elements("Ingredients").Elements("Ingredient"))
{

    Details content = new Details();
    // initialize other values 
    content.IngredientName = item.Element("Name").Value;
    content.IngredientQuantity = item.Element("Quantity").Value;
    content.IngredientUnit = item.Element("Unit").Value;
    contentList.Add(content);
}
```